# How to write to any file but existing regular files using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I made the following attempts .. in vain:

1. hello.sh using "test -f"

```
#! /bin/bash
test -f $1 && exit 1 || echo "hello" > $1
```

Unfortunately, `$ ./hello.sh /dev/stdout > non_existent` does no writing.

2. hello2.sh using "set -C"

```
#! /bin/bash
set -C; echo "hello" > $1
```

Also, `$ ./hello2.sh /dev/stdout > non_existent` still does not work.

I guess when redirecting, bash calls `freopen("/dev/stdout", "w", $1)`, which wrongly makes **/dev/stdout** look like an existing regular file.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: No, `/dev/stdout` is just a symlink to file descriptor 1 of the calling proess, whatever that happens to be. For `hello.sh` and `hello2.sh`, file descriptor 1 is the file `non_existent`. `test` fails because `/dev/stdout` is a symlink which is not a regular file. For the `echo` commands stdout is also `non_existent` but for a different reason.

Comment: Also, when you run a script (or other command) with output redirected with `> filename`, the shell creates (or truncates) that file and opens it as fd 1 *before running the script*. Thus, by the time the script is running, it already exists (probably as a regular file, though it might be a symlink, device, etc). If you want the script to know about and/or control its output redirection, you have to pass the filename as a regular parameter and have the script itself do the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply close the standard file-descriptors during (only) the test:

```
$ test -f /dev/stdout <&- >&- 2>&-
$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [exec](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/exec.1posix.html). Try the shell script below

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 7<&1 # Make file descriptor 7 a copy of stdout
[ -f "$1" ] && echo "File ${1} exists" && exit 1
# At this point we can confirm the file doesn't exist
exec 1>"$1"
echo "Bingo" # This goes to the file
# Now revert the value of STDOUT using the copy we made
exec 1<&7
# For testing, the output should print at stdout
cat "$1"
```

Test the script with

```
./script.sh outfile
```